# Sensitivity equations with discontinuities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on solving pharmacometric problems using ordinary differential equations of low dimensionality. For example, a common simple model looks like this:

$$\dot{A} = -KA$$

where $A$ is the amount of a drug in blood plasma, and $K$ is the elimination rate, in units of 1/time.

It is desired to know how $A$ varies with changes in $K$. Define $G = \partial A/\partial K$. Then we can write a "sensitivity equation":

$$\dot{G} = -KG - A$$

This is all well known, but what is not well known is how to handle discontinuities at particular time points, such as doses $A = A + D$, or simply setting $A$ to zero $A = 0$. What do we do with $G$ at those time points?
I've tentatively concluded that adding something to $A$ does not affect $G$, but multiplying $A$ by some factor, like $0$, should also be applied to $G$.

I would appreciate any insight I may be lacking on this.

For what it's worth, here is some documentation on CVODES, by Serban and Hindmarsh:

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you write $dA/dK $ do you really mean $\partial A/\partial K $ with time fixed? If so, is the dosing structure also fixed? If so then there is no problem, your ODE for the sensitivity works the same way. Maybe it is non-obvious what the value of $G $ and hence it's derivative should be exactly at the discontinuity, but if you understand everything on either side of the discontinuity then there is not really any issue with that.

Comment: @Ian: I wasn't sure how to format the partial, thanks. I think of it like an engineer (which I am). If the dose is 1mg at time 10, I run the ODEs up to time 10, then add 1 to A, then run forward again. I think that means no change to G at that time, because if A were different by epsilon, A+1 would be also. But there's another case where A needs to be cleared to 0, and I think in that case G must also be cleared. So I see just those two cases, additive and proportional, which seem to be special cases of a more general rule, that I was looking for insight on.

Comment: I think your concern is then that if $A $ is zero at some moment then the dynamics are halted so that there is no longer any dependence on $K $. At this point from a computational perspective you have $G=0$ but from a physical perspective, asking for $G $ is now "the wrong question". But provided that $A $ has never been zero over the course of the dynamics, the sensitivity still makes sense. The problem is that if it has been zero then the impact of $K $ should be integrated over "less time" (canceling the fact that the dynamics were stopped for some time).

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for bearing with me. I'm starting to think that if at a time point we say $A = f(A)$, then we should also say $G = \partial f(A)/\partial A$. So if $f(A)$ is $A+D$ we multiply $G$ by $1$, and if $f(A)$ is $A Q$ then we multiply $G$ by $Q$. If $f(A)$ is $(A+D)Q$ it multiplies $G$ by $Q$. To me this looks chain-rule-ish. Make sense?

Comment: @Ian: I meant to say $G=G \times \partial f(A)/\partial A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this problem seems to be complicated, but in this simple case you can be rather explicit. Consider the problem:

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=kx+f(t),x(k,t=0)=x_0.$$

The solution to this problem is

$$x(k,t)=e^{kt} \left ( x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-ks} f(s) ds \right ).$$

Thus the derivative with respect to $k$ is

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial k}(k,t)=t e^{kt} \left ( x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-ks} f(s) ds \right ) - e^{kt} \left ( \int_0^t s e^{-ks} f(s) ds \right ).$$

Differentiating that with respect to $t$ gives

$$\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t \partial k} = e^{kt} \left ( kt + 1 \right ) \left ( x_0 + \int_0^t e^{-ks} f(s) ds \right ) - k e^{kt} \int_0^t s e^{-ks} f(s) ds - t f(t)$$

If $f$ is just zero then this reduces to your equation, but otherwise the situation is quite a bit more complicated even in this relatively simple situation, as you can see.

That said, you can implement your case of interest by considering $f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta(t-t_i)$; these correspond to dosages of size $a_i$ at times $t_i$.

By the way, if you are careful about the order of multiplication, everything I did above translates to higher dimensions. It also translates to general inhomogeneous linear equations, provided that you can construct the necessary Green's function for them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that you can model this with delta functions. I have to approach it from an engineering viewpoint (i.e. write a program) and also handle the general case, not just linear. The example I gave was just for explanation. But I don't hear that I'm missing the target very widely, and I appreciate the answer. My own math skills (such as they are) come to similar conclusions.

Comment: I don't think the nonlinear case has any nice expression, even in terms of the solution to some special case of the problem (e.g. the Green's function for a complicated linear ODE).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Also, a computational technique for studying the parameter dependence of the solution to an ODE is called numerical continuation. There is a really great implementation of this method with an adequate Python interface in the program AUTO 07p.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you might want to look into the huge amount of literature on Michaelis–Menten kintetics, which can be used to describe when A is large enough that the path for elimination of drug is saturated. There, dC/dt = Vmax.C/(C + km), where C is the concentration of drug, Vmax and Km are constants. When C is small in relation to km, then dC/dt ~ (Vmax/km).C, which is like your first equation. However, this is more related to how A affects K, in the terminology of your first equation.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty familiar with MM kinetics. The question was about sensitivity with respect to parameter changes, for which the  technique of sensitivity equations was developed. Along the way, my colleagues and I became aware of the method called "complex step differentiation". We never really got to run with it, but you might find it interesting.

Comment: I see. Complex analysis approach. I will keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: If I had been aware of that method early enough, we would have tried to make use of it. It's a nifty idea, but would have required a lot of adaptation.